# Как создать и запустить контейнер на основе образа?

Tags: docker

Есть образ *hihozhou/php-opencv* . Хочу сделать контейнер на основе этого образа чтобы запустить контейнер, писать код и видеть результат в браузере.

Почитал про докер и попробовал сделать так:

1. создал Dockerfile с таким содержанием:

```
FROM hihozhou/opencv:latest
COPY range.php /php-opencv/opencv
EXPOSE 5000
```

2. Сбилдал

```
docker build -t name/image .
```

3. Запустил

```
docker run -p 8888:5000 name/image
```

Ожидал увидеть страницу range.php в браузере, но нечего не произошло.

Наверное я не совсем разобрался в докере.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать контейнер на основе образа *hihozhou/php-opencv* чтобы запустить контейнер, писать код и видеть результат в браузере?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: а вы открыли `localhost:8888` ?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, открыть в браузере? Вижу _This site can’t be reached. localhost refused to connect._. Возможно я не понимаю как работать с портами.

Comment: вы пропустили буквы `php-` и скачали не тот из [двух образов](https://hub.docker.com/u/hihozhou)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, это да. Спасибо что заметили. Но это не решило проблему. Изменил имя образа / сбилдал заново / запустил. При выполнении `docker ps` свой контейнер не вижу. При выполнении `docker ps -a` свой контейнер вижу. Перешел в bash своего контейнера и вижу что файл range.php скопировался. Проблема только в том чтобы запустить в браузере.

Comment: *При выполнении docker ps свой контейнер не вижу* — значит, либо вы его не запускали, либо он сам остановился после запуска. начните с создания контейнера из исходного образа. а потом доберётесь и до создания своего образа.